# resignFirstResponder when pressing another textfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I can't resign the first responder of a UITextField when he presses on another textfield that brings up a picker view. Here is my code.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if (type.editing == YES) { 
    [name resignFirstResponder];
}
```

I have this in view did load.

```
type.delegate=self;
name.delegate=self;
```

I don't know why this happens.Please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At he moment this delegate method is called, is name your first responder? try checking like this

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
  if (type == textField && [name isFirstResponder]) { 
    [name resignFirstResponder];
  }
}
```